# How do I install (both) miniconda2 and miniconda3 side-by-side

Tags: miniconda

I need to use programmes (pipelines) written for miniconda2 (py2) as well as separate one written for miniconda3 (py3).  How do I install miniconda2 and miniconda3 side-by-side and then easily switch between them both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are approaching this from the wrong direction. Only install one of them (i.e. miniconda3). The only difference is which python version is installed in the `base` environment. For different python versions, simply create different environments instead of having seperate `conda` installations. After installing miniconda3, simply do

```
conda create -n py2 python=2.7
conda create -n py3 python=3.x
```

replacing 3.x with the version you actually need. Then selectively do

```
conda activate py2
```

to get to python2
or

```
conda activate py3
```

to get to python 3

Comment: Thanks for this answer!